# JUnit test another method that uses fail()

Tags: java, junit

We have a rather complex object that is the result of calling our drools engine.
For JUnit testing our rules we create a RulesTestHelper class that offers a method `"assertOurObject(OurObject expected, OurObject actual)"` and does many assertions on the elements of OurObject (This might probably be solved better by writing our own Matcher but we aren't that far yet).

Now in our method "assertOurObject" the first check is done if any of the objects is null, like this:

```
    if (expected == null || actual == null)
      fail("Expected or actual is null");
```

Now I want to JUnit test this method and assert that when I set one of the two objects to "null" I will fail the test. So in other words, I expect the test to fail and this should be ok.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: So you want to write a test that tests the test? And what about using `Objects.requireNonNull(expected);` since Java 7. It'll throw a NPE if expected is null, which you can easily test with JUnit by saying you expect a NPE to be thrown.

Comment: does anything happen when you send a null object to the method? You can junit test that fact.

Comment: Since this change may affect all the tests, I recommend you to create a new method where one of the parameters may be `null`, otherwise the test must fail. This is easier to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change your code, you can use a solution similar to what Anderson Vieira said but instead use

```
@Test(expected=AssertionError.class)
```

The junit `fail()` method throws an AssertionError that you can specifically expect

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for pointing that out. My point is still valid, `fail()` throws an Error and since `@Test` can catch a Throwable, we can expect that - you only need to check the specific type your version of JUnit throws.

Comment: @JBNizet changed according to your comment to support latest JUnit, I was looking at the source of an archaic version of JUnit

Answer (score 0):

You could throw an exception when this case occurs and tell the test to expect it by annotating it with:

```
@Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
public void testShouldFailIfAnyObjectIsNull() {
    ... // do something
    if (expected == null || actual == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    ... // do something
}
```